# Dealing with Backward Slash when Creating File object on Windows

Tags: java, windows, windows-10, jakarta-mail

I am constructing a `File` object to be used as an e-mail attachment. I am working on Eclipse on Windows 10.
The filename `String` provided in the constructor is in the format `/path/to/file`.

```
File attachment = new File(fileName);
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachment);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
...
```

However upon mail sending I get the following exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: \path\to\file (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I checked the File `getPath()` and `toString()` methods to find out that the object is created with backwards slash "\"

This is how the File class resolves the separator:

```
public static final String separator = SystemProperties.getProperty("file.separator");
```

and then replaces the forward slashes with backward ones.

Is there any way to make Java use forward slashes on Windows?

Comment: Use forward `/`, it will work both in windows as well as unix.

Comment: you can also use `"\\path\\to\\file"`

Comment: What do you expect? Windows uses backward slashes as path separator. Do you want a file that contains forward slashes in its name?

Comment: Are you sure the file really exists at that path?

Comment: @Bill Shannon yes

Comment: I doubt the problem has anything to do with slashes or backslashes.  How do you know the file really exists?  Are you using Windows Explorer to view the file?  If you use the Java File.list method, does it show the file?  Does it show the directory containing the file?  Is the file created by your program or by some other program?  Does the file exist both before and after your program runs?